# How to get onload function working in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am having some troubles here:

```
function load(){
    var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield');
        for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            elements[i].addEventListener("keydown",keydown);
        }
  }

window.onload = load;
```

This is my JavaScript which works perfectly fine with this HTML **outside** my Ionic app:

```
        <input class="zipCode inputfield" />
```

Yet, it is **not working in Ionic**! I have no errors in the console or whatsoever...

I tried this too:

```
<body onload="load();">
   <input class="zipCode inputfield" />
</body>
```

But it didn't do the trick either.

I am out of options, as this is perfectly valid JS. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", load, false) ;

function load(){
    var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield');
    for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        elements[i].addEventListener("keydown",keydown);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you are working with ionic better to use view [life cycle and events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) . There are number of events  you could find in their [document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

eg.

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
            //do your work here..
        })
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not an answer to my question.